# Fibonacci Sequence error

Tags: eclipse, fibonacci

I am coding a Fibonacci sequence in Eclipse and this is my code-

```
public class FibonacciAlgorithm {
    private int a = 0;
    private int b = 1;

    public FibonacciAlgorithm() {
    }

    public int increment() {
        int temp = b;
        b = a + b;
        a = temp;
        return value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

It is showing an error in the `return value;` line saying `value cannot be resolved to a variable`. I don't see any other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `value` defined? You return something that was not defined anywhere.

Comment: I see now, what would I define `value` as?

Comment: You probably want to return b.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is returning an int variable so you would have to define and return `value` as an int

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "value" defined, this is your error. I don't remember the thing exactly, but I think you don't need a and b, I found this in my code archive, hope it helps.

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    public static long fibo(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1) return n;
        else return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
    }

    public static void main() {
        int count = 5; // change accordingly, bind to input etc.
        int N = Integer.parseInt(count);
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + fibo(i));
        }
}
```

In case you want to stay with your own code, try returning "b" as value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you trying to do.
If you have "getValue" method I think "increment" method should be void.
When you want current Fibonacci value use "getValue" method.

```
    public class FibonacciAlgorithm {

        private int a = 0;
        private int b = 1;     

        public FibonacciAlgorithm() {

        }

        public void increment() {
            int temp = b;
            b = a + b;
            a = temp;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return b;
        }
```